# Why would I assign the result of lm() to lm.fit?

Tags: r

From "An Introduction to Statistical Learning", Sec. 3.6.2, I get this code (to perform a linear regression):

```
library(MASS)
library(ISLR2)
lm.fit =lm(medv~lstat ,data=Boston )
```

My understanding is that `lm.fit` is the basic fitter function for linear models. Why would I overwrite it with the result of `lm()`? Then `lm.fit` stops being a function and becomes a list. Shouldn't I just assign the result of `lm()` to a new variable?

Comment: Yes, it's better not to overwrite a variable which is already assigned to a function in the namespace of a loaded package, as this is likely to produce all sorts of unexpected side effects. Variable names like `l1`, `fit1` etc. are pretty safe in this regard.

Comment: Yes, avoiding name clashes would be best practice. Textbooks don't always do this. Many online examples will use `df` as a dataframe, but this is also a base R function.

Comment: @dardisco, please post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker this might be too opinion-based a question to give a cited answer, particularly without knowing the textbook in question, which may have reasons for using this particular naming scheme (unlikely, but not impossible)

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with the textbook. It's very good overall, but I wouldn't be at all surprised that the R code is this sloppy ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, posting as an answer.

It is best practice **not** to overwrite a variable which is already defined in the namespace of a loaded package, in order to avoid unwanted side-effects. Variable names of the form `var1`, `lm2` etc. are typically safe choices in this regard. Hadley Wickham's [Style Guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) recommends `var_1`, `lm_2`, although personally those underscores can get a little tiresome if you are using the 'smart underscore' in [ESS](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EssSmartUnderscore) (changes `_` to `<-`).

We can always check before assigning to a variable with e.g.

```
(if (!exists("lm.fit")) lm.fit  <- lm(medv ~ lstat, data=ISLR2::Boston))
```

which gives `NULL`, indicating that `lm.fit` already exists.

Assigning `lm.fit` is not a cardinal offense, as `lm` still works as expected as well as the function `lm.fit`, as we can see:

```
lm.fit  <- lm(medv ~ lstat, data=ISLR2::Boston)
lm(medv ~ lstat, data=ISLR2::Boston)
### Manually adding an intercept term below to get the same results
lm.fit(x=cbind(rep(1, length(Boston$lstat)), Boston$lstat),
   y=Boston$medv)$coefficients
```

That is, `lm.fit` is still found as a function when called as such as it remains defined in the namespace of the package `stats`, as shown by:

```
getAnywhere(lm.fit)
```

giving

```
2 differing objects matching ‘lm.fit’ were found
in the following places
  .GlobalEnv
  package:stats
  namespace:stats
Use [] to view one of them
```